# Netbeans IDE not installing as a root user in CentOS

Tags: java, netbeans, centos7

trying to install the netbeans ide on my centos pc using ./netbeans-8.0.1-linux.sh and I keep getting the message saying permission denied even though am logged in as the root...what am I not doing right? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

is netbeans-8.0.1-linux.sh executable?

Try:

```
chmod u+x netbeans-8.0.1-linux.sh
```

Also you should be able to install it as a regular user.

Answer (score 1):

open terminal. Then goto that folder containing netbeansfiles. Then type

```
sudo chmod -R 777 foldername
```

This will give give full permission to folder and its contents.